# Razor + Html.Raw() with white space?

Tags: css, razor

Why does the following work:

```
@if(Page.SomeVar == "VALUE"){
    @Html.Raw(".classStyle{border:1px solid #000} #idStyle{border:1px solid #000}")
}
```

Yet this breaks:

```
@if(Page.SomeVar == "VALUE"){
    @Html.Raw("
       .classStyle{border:1px solid #000}
       #idStyle{border:1px solid #000}
    ")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Razor in C# you need to use `@` if you want to have [multiple line](http://jameskovacs.com/2007/02/12/multiline-strings-in-c/) [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
@if(Page.SomeVar == "VALUE"){
    @Html.Raw(@"
       .classStyle{border:1px solid #000}
       #idStyle{border:1px solid #000}
    ")
}
```